# With Angular - How to Pre-Select a Option that gets repeated out if a value exist?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

So what I am trying to do is pass a parameter in the url to a page with a select being repeated out.  The parameter passing is customerProfile.id.  Then I am trying to find that customerProfile.id in the select options and select it.  How do I go about that?  So if customerProfile.id exist select corresponding option if not default.  The ids being spit out are all like 1,2,3,4,5, etc... If you need more info let me know.

Here is the select:

```
<div class="form-group" id="testpick">
   <label for="field_customerProfile">customerProfile</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="field_customerProfile" name="customerProfile"
     ng-model="rentalAgreement.customerProfile"
     ng-options="customerProfile as customerProfile.lastName for customerProfile in customerprofiles track by customerProfile.id">
      <option value=""></option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Tried this with the 1 being replaced later with the parameter.

```
angular.element('div#testpick select').val('1');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `ng-model` you could store only the customer id instead of the whole customer object, i.e. replace `ng-options="customerProfile ...` with `ng-options="customerProfile.id ...`:

```
<select class="..." id="..." name="..." ng-model="rentalAgreement.customerProfileId" ng-options="customerProfile.id as customerProfile.lastName for customerProfile in customerprofiles track by customerProfile.id">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Then the idea is to set the variable binded to the `ng-model`, i.e. `rentalAgreement.customerProfile`, to the parameter value from the url, which is the customer id. If the setted value matches one of the options, the select list will point on that value. You could retrieve the url parameter by injecting `$location` in the controller, and look into `$location.search()`:

#### Controller

Assuming the url parameter is named *customerId*:

```
$scope.rentalAgreement = {
    customerProfileId: $location.search().customerId
}
```